# Getting an error "error: expected expression before..." when I try to call a function with parameters in C

Tags: c, function, call, declare

My code looks like:

```
FILE *test
char line[50];
fp = fopen(arg[5], "r");

doSomething(File test, char line[50]);  // declare function
doSomething(fp, line[50]); // call function
```

I am getting an "expected error expression before 'FILE' error. I've tried many different variations of the syntax, but I still get this error, or more errors. I realize when I call the function, I just need to have the arguments within the same scope and to declare the function beforehand, which I thought I did.

I just want to be able to call the function without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is, without a forward declaration, the first *assummed* declaration is actually being interpreted as a function call [implicit declaration of a function]. There, the `File test` is being interpreted as *actual argument*, not a parameter. There, `FILE` being a reserved keyword and `File test` being no valid argument, the error is thrown.

In your code for the function *declaration*, move th3 declaration outside `main()`, please specify the return type for the function and correct the type of first parameter.

Change

```
 doSomething(File test, char line[50]);
```

to

```
 int doSomething(File * test, char line[50]);
```

Note: Always enable [and pay attention to] compiler warnings. With warnings enabled, your compiler should show you the warning

> warning: implicit declaration of function

in these cases.

Also, the call is wrong. `line[50]` will reference the character just after your array. Change the call to:

```
doSomething(fp, line); // call function
```

Comment: It was less work to add it to the best existing answer than to write up a complete answer myself. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
doSomething(File test, char line[50]);
```

should be

```
doSomething(File *test, char line[50]);
```

I see that the function fopen() returns `FILE *` and you are trying to pass the return value to your function `doSomething()` so the first argument should be of type `FILE *` and not `FILE`

```
void doSomething( FILE *f,char a[])
{
  // Do your stuff
}

int main()
{
  char b[100] = "";
  FILE *fp = fopen("file","mode");
  doSomething(fp,b);
}
```

Comment: That's actually one of the things I tried already, and I get the same error doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of function should be like this.

```
     doSomething(File *, char);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file in C, a pointer to the beginning of the file is returned. This is what you should pass around and not the actual file.
The right was is as Gopi suggested.